# Dialog Size fills screen, not wrap content

Tags: android, dialog

we developed an app mostly tested on a Galaxy Nexus.

Now after some testing on other devices, we see that a dialog with title, some message and ok/cancel button on some devices (specially Nexus S) doesn't fit "wrap content". the Dialog is about 80% filled over the sreen

it looks like:

//start
Title
Border
Message
Button1 Button2
"free space"
"free space"
"free space"
//end

The used library is https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs

Does anybody know this occurrences???

it appears to us that looks terrible

app can be found at playstore in countries Germany, Switzerland and Austria called "Narbage"
( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edelapps.narbage )

maybe it is a problem of android build versions < 4.3

thanks
tom

Comment: Have U tried using custom dialogs

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ctx, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(com.example.e_mbmpphe.R.drawable.popupbackground);
    linearLayout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

    TextView logoTxt = new TextView(ctx);
    logoTxt.setTextSize(20);
    logoTxt.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
    logoTxt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    TextView lineTxt = new TextView(ctx);
    TextView lineTxtup = new TextView(ctx);

    lineTxt.setBackgroundResource(com.example.e_mbmpphe.R.drawable.linebackground);
    lineTxtup.setBackgroundResource(com.example.e_mbmpphe.R.drawable.linebackground);

    TextView errormsgTxt = new TextView(ctx);
    errormsgTxt.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
    errormsgTxt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    errormsgTxt.setTextSize(29);

    LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(ctx);
    linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    Button saveBtn = new Button(ctx);
    saveBtn.setTextSize(20);
    saveBtn.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
    saveBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    saveBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 4f));

    Button cancelBtn = new Button(ctx);
    cancelBtn.setTextSize(20);
    cancelBtn.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
    cancelBtn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    cancelBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 4f));

    linearLayout.addView(logoTxt);
    linearLayout.addView(lineTxtup);
    linearLayout.addView(errormsgTxt);
    linearLayout.addView(lineTxt);
    linearLayout.addView(linearLayout2);
    linearLayout2.addView(saveBtn);
    linearLayout2.addView(cancelBtn);

        logoTxt.setText(" Alert !!!");
        errormsgTxt.setText("Are you sure you want to Restore "+workTitle+ " Work");


    saveBtn.setText("Yes");
    cancelBtn.setText("No");
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db.upadteremoveWorkFromWorkListStatus(workId, "false");
            fillWork();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }


    });

    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    dialog.setContentView(linearLayout);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    lp.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    lp.x=-170;
    lp.y=100;
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

change the onCreateDialog method in BaseDialogFragment to ...
-> no use of the inmite.dialog style reference.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow();
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    return dialog;
}
```